# Eloquent triple relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm having a hard time understanding on how to model a triple relation in Laravel.

I have 3 models: User, Tour and Photo

Each tour has users associated with it and all users can post photos. Which means the database looks something like this:

id , tour_id, user_id, photo_id

This way I know which user posted which photo for which tour. My question is, how do I model this in Eloquent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update Based on your last comment.

The simplest answer to your question is by using relations **belongsToMany** and **hasMany**.

Let me explain. 
You need 4 table users, tours, tour_user and photos.

users table contain id,name

tours table contain id,name,

tour_user table contain id,tour_id,user_id

photos table contain id,name,user_id,tour_id

Why **belongsToMany** ? because each user has more than one tour and each tour has more than one users. So we link both tables by using a third table tour_user. It also helps in normalization.

Now that we have examined the table structure for the relationship, let's define it on the User model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{

    public function tours()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tour');
    }
    /* To retrieve photos of a user */
    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Photo');
    }

}
```

Tour model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tour extends Model
{

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
    /* To retrieve photos of a tour*/
    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Photo');
    }

}
```

Now Photo model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Photo extends Model
{

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function tours()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Tour');
    }

}
```

Now let find all tour of a specific user by using

```
public function show($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    return view('show')->withUser($user) ;
}
```

Now in show view, page lets extract all tours of that user and his photos

```
@foreach($user->tours as $tour)
     {{ $tour->name }}
     @foreach($tour->photos as $photo)
         @if($user->id == $photo->user_id)
         {{ $photo->name }}
         @endif
     @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: I need to retreive the photos for a specific user given a specific tour. I don't see how this solves my problem

Comment: Use foreach($user->photos as $photo){ $photo->name;}

Comment: @kjanko I completely update by answer based on your requirements. hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should have: **one to many** Tour > user and
**one to many** User > Photo

include this function in your Tour model.

```
public function allusers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class);
    }
```

and this in your User model.

```
public function allphotos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Photos::class);
    }
```

Then you can get a tour `$tour = Tour::find(1);`

and just use the function to get the users with this:

```
$usersOnTour = $tour->allusers();
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have a `user_id` foriegn key field in your `tour model` and 'photo_id' foriegn key field in your `user moel`

the trick is to have `user model` with a hasOne/hasMany relationship with `photo model` and then have `tour model` with a hasOne/hasMany relationship with the `user model`.

1 - first in your `user model` define a relationship like this

```
public function photo()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Photo');
}
```

2 - In your `tour model` define a hasMany relationship like this

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

so when you fetch a tour model like

`$a = tour::All();`
you can do 

`$a->users->'field_in_user_table'
or 
$a->users->photo; // to get the photo field value from photo table`

Comment: This won't return the photo for the given tour, but all the photos for users that belong to a certain tour. A user can belong in many tours.

Comment: @kjanko oh, I thought the picture in question where the profile picture of the users.